# Disable button after returning from an intent

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Afternoon all I need to call an intent and upon returning disable the button for X seconds.
I have tried variations of the following, which either disable the button immediately and then enable or do not do what I need full stop.

```
        Guarding.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Guarding.setEnabled(false);
                SharedPref.write(SharedPref.SCANTYPE,"GUARDING");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Menu.this, CmxScanner.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                Guarding.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Guarding.setEnabled(true);
                        //Log.d(TAG,"resend1");
                    }
                },10000);
            }
        });
```

So on first entry to the menu i have a button that is enabled, after clicking it must call the intent and upon returning disable the button again for X seconds. Before it will enable and allow a second request to the Intent

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Could you elaborate on your question a bit more? What do you mean when you say "upon returning"? What is the exact behaviour you want to show? (couldn't figure this out from your question)

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. I have a button that triggers an intent. I perform some actions in the intent and when finished come back to the calling intent. Upon returning to the calling intent I need to disable the button that called it for a short period of time

Answer (score 0):

You can register your calling activity for a result as explained in the Android docs [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result). Then in the result callback you simply enable the button after 10 seconds:

```
ActivityResultLauncher<String> mGetContent = registerForActivityResult(new GetContent(),
    new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(Uri uri) {
            Guarding.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Guarding.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }, 10000);
        }
    }
});
```